# Serving assets from subdirectory w/ Sprockets in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, sprockets

I have a Sinatra app where I'm serving Sprockets assets from `/assets`. Works well enough, but since I'm a bit of a perfectionist, and to keep things as tidy as possible, I would like to have the assets served from their respective subdirectories.
I.e. I would like `#{root}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` to be served as `/assets/stylesheets/application.css`, instead of just `/assets/application.css` as it is now.

Is this possible? Middleman does something similar to this, but I'm not sure how much it's actually leaning on Sprockets.

Answer (score 0):

[Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) is a *static* site generator, and therefore the assets are precompiled and served as if they were in a [public directory](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Static%20Files), which means that you could have a subdir of `stylesheets` and it would become part of the url used to access the assets in the subdir.

[Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) compiles assets as they are accessed and then caches them (as far as I can see), and uses a [Rack application](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/server.rb) to serve the assets from their *logical path*. From the Sprockets README:

> The logical path is the path of the asset source file relative to its
>   containing directory in the load path. For example, if your load path
>   contains the directory app/assets/javascripts:
>
> Asset source file | Logical path
>   app/assets/javascripts/application.js | application.js
>   app/assets/javascripts/models/project.js | models/project.js

I didn't see an obvious setting to change in the docs, and unless you're willing to look through the source and hack a bit, then I'd say the answer is no. Maybe you could try shortening the load path and see if it includes the subdirs?

Comment: Middleman uses a dynamic server while in development mode (and is built on Padrino which is built on Sinatra), and leverages Sprockets for includes, etc. So my thinking is it should be possible to emulate this behavior in a vanilla Sinatra app as well.

Comment: The server is orthogonal, what matters is whether the assets are pre-compiled or compiled on access to the page.  Middleman [does](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/3.0-stable/middleman-core/middleman-core.gemspec) [not](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/3.0-stable/middleman-more/middleman-more.gemspec) use Sprockets, there is [another gem for this](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-sprockets), and it doesn't compile on access, it precompiles.

Comment: [See the docs](http://middlemanapp.com/asset-pipeline/), Sprockets is provided by the Rails asset pipeline, and is not part of Middleman, but _if it is there you can use it_ - just like any other library.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. I guess then that my question is rather: how can I leverage Sprockets-like `require` statements for JavaScript in my Sinatra app, without using the complete assets pipeline?

Comment: @JohanSahlén I'm not clear on what you mean, do you [mean this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)? Personally, I just use Guard to precompile on save and stick the results straight into public in subfolders, I don't see the need for all the complexity that Sprockets/the asset pipeline brings. Then again, I don't understand why most of Rails is needed which is probably why I prefer Sinatra! :)

Comment: Well, what I like sprockets for is really the `require` functionality – just being able to do `require_tree ./lib` in my main JavaScript file is invaluable. So, in the best of worlds I would like to have that functionality, but serve the files (precompiled in production and compile-on-request in development) from custom folders.